# How to uninstall a bower package using gitbash?

Tags: bower, timepicker, bower-install

I want to uninstall my - time picker which is - "bootstrap-timepicker": "~0.3.0" (in bower.json) and I guess its overlapping - "bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker": "~1.2.1", which I need.

I tired the uninstall command and it just did the following:

```
$ bower uninstall bootstrap-timepicker
bower uninstall     bootstrap-timepicker
bower uninstall     autotype
```

So how can I really uninstall and remove dependency from bower.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ bower uninstall bootstrap-timepicker --save
```

http://bower.io/docs/api/#uninstall